# Scrape content from web page

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

My question regards scraping data from the following site:

https://www.google.dk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=swarovski+london&tbs=lf:1,lf_ui:4&tbm=lcl&start=0&rllag=51537201,-182623,5184&rlha=0

Ideally, I want to count the number of (active) stores in the city by reading the store name and whether the store is closed into R.

I have tried the following without luck:

Attempt 1 -

```
url <- "https://www.google.dk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=swarovski%20london&rflfq=1&rlha=0&rllag=51537201,-182623,5184&tbm=lcl&tbs=lf:1,lf_ui:4&rlfi=hd:;si:"

read_html(url)
```

Attempt 2 -

```
webdata <- html(url)

webdata %>%
        html_nodes("._rl") %>%
        html_text()
```

Anyone who has a clue on how to deal with this?

Thank you very much.

Kind regards,

Daniel

Comment: Check Google's terms and conditions about scraping their data

Comment: They probably have an API set up for this sort of thing. Maybe it's the Places API, not sure though. https://developers.google.com/places/

Comment: Hi cory. Thanks for your answer. It sure looks promising, but seems like some higher level coding is required. Will look into it asap.